# Rewrite or change the permalinks like Wordpress in moodle

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, moodle

I am working on the Moodle I want to change the permalinks like Wordpress. I want to use the page name as URL suffix. mod_rewrite not working for me.

from

```
www.domain.com/mod/page/view.php?id=431
```

to

```
www.domain.com/aboutus
```

what is the possibility that I can do this? I researched on moodle docs but no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aboutus$ /mod/page/view.php?id=431 [L]
```

This should take the URL `www.domain.com/mod/page/view.php?id=431` and leave you with `www.domain.com/aboutus`.

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

If you have issues with the above, you can try it using `{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=431$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /aboutus/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your moodle running in apache server, then place `.htaccess` file in root folder

In `.htaccess` file

```
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# The path to the Moodle instance e.g. /moodle/
RewriteBase /

##############################  COURSE  ##############################

# course/{name,idnumber,id}/<value of the provided key>
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule course/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$  course/view.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

# course/<id, i.e. Moodle magic number>
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}          course/([\d]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule course/(.+)$            course/view.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# course/<value, i.e. shortname>
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}          course/([^\d]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule course/(.+)$            course/view.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
#
######################################################################
```

Or Easiest way is use this module.
https://github.com/brendanheywood/moodle-local_cleanurls